# add next, prev buttons in image slider made by recyclerView

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview

I've made Image slider with the help of `recyclerView` and `SnapHelper`. I have also added next, prev imageView under the recyclerView.

I want to implement them to work as next,prev. Their id are next, prev respectively.

This is activity where imageSlider is shown:

```java
public class RajeshDaiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RajeshDaiAdapter.OnNoteListener {
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rajesh_dai);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_image);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.oq, null));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.oqqqq, null));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.opt3, null));



        RajeshDaiAdapter adapter = new RajeshDaiAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.addItems(wordList);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add ItemClickListenener to RecyclerView. But you can not add onItemClick directly. you can found that on google.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani could you please give me link? please?

Comment: use this library as snap recyclerview implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.3' use my answer for your image view click solution 

Comment: It didn't worked please help me @AliAmini

Answer (score 0):

add this in your main class

```
int CurrenePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
NextItemImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CurrenePosition < recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1)
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(CurrenePosition + 1);
        }
    });
PreviousItemImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CurrenePosition > 0)
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(CurrenePosition - 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you haven't used ID of imageView or take any refrence form XML??
```ImageView NextItemImageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);``` this should be above ```setOnClickListener``` ?? right???

Comment: no, you have to declare your image view before using them 
add Id to your image view and declare it in your java class and then you can use them.

Comment: while clicking "next" every time first position image is showing and while cicking "prev" no reaction is there.

Comment: It didn't worked. I am using recyclerView to display images.

Comment: can you use view pager?

Comment: please help me? I want to make this in recycler view please?