# create next and prev below image made by recyclerView

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview

I've made a imageSlider by the help of `recyclerView`. Now, I want to make`button` below it i.e, next and previous work as its name. I've done in XML, but is confused in code. please help me.

this is main activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.da, null));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, null));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.oq, null));

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter (this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.addItems(wordList);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly share the layouts

Comment: activity_main contains recyclerView and another activty contains imageview. I can make next and prev buttons but am confusing in code. please help me?? @ViVekH

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036610/add-next-prev-buttons-in-image-slider-made-by-recyclerview

Comment: @ViVekH it didnot worked, the answer given there is not workig.